# Use the underlying Socket/ServerSocket in a SocketChannel/ServerSocketChannel?

Tags: java, selector, nio

I'm trying the Java.nio-package for non-blocking communication. So I got my ServerSocketChannel and all my connected clients (SocketChannel) in a Selector and wait for data (OP_ACCEPT/OP_READ) using Selector.select().

My question is: Can I - instead of using a ByteBuffer and read directly with SocketChannel.read() - use the underlying Socket, get an InputStream and read using that stream? Or will that mess up the selector-stuff?

Comment: read() is a blocking operation. Only NIO can be used in a blocking or non blocking mode. IO is only blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29

If this socket has an associated channel then the resulting input stream delegates all of its operations to the channel. If the channel is in non-blocking mode then the input stream's read operations will throw an IllegalBlockingModeException.

Comment: Ah - okey. I really don't like how SocketChannel and ByteBuffer works. I just want to read n bytes, but SocketChannel.read() only reads either until the ByteBuffer is full, or until there is no more data in the SocketChannel. Is there a simple way to just read n bytes?

Comment: @Simon not in non-blocking mode.